# Display template for editing a list attribute in model returns null on form submit

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a model that contains a class like `Days` where `Days` are a collection of `Day`.

This is what the entity framework autogenerated model looks like:

```
public MyModel()
        {
            this.ExceptionDays = new HashSet<ExceptionDay>();
            this.RegularDays = new HashSet<RegularDay>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ExceptionDay> ExceptionDays { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<RegularDay> RegularDays { get; set; }
    }
```

The RegularDay & ExceptionDay are, both, separate classes in separate files under the autogenerated model.
Now, the create form for this model needs to take a `Day` and add it to the list `Days`. I figured I'd use a display template for doing this.

This is what my create display view looks like:

```
@model MyModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">

        <hr />           

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-10">
        **@Html.EditorFor(model => model.RegularDays, "ICollection_RegularDay_Edit")**
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-10">
                **@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ExceptionDays, "ICollection_ExceptionDay_Edit")**
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

My Edit template looks like this:

```
@model RegularDay

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.dayOfWeek)

    <div class="col-md-">
        <div class="col-md-">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.dayOfWeek, new SelectList(
    new List<Object>
    {
               "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"
    }
    ))
        </div>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.dayOfWeek, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.startTime)

    <div class="col-md-">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.startTime, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @*@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.startTime, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })*@
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NumberOfHours)

    <div class="col-md-">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.NumberOfHours, new SelectList(
    new List<Object>
    {
                1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
    }
    ))
    </div>
</div>
```

The other display template for edit is similar.

**Now the problem is, that my controller never gets the regularDay or ExceptionDay in the model that the view returns on post.**

My controller method looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Name,Description, RegularDays, ExceptionDays")] MyModel myModel)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {    
                db.LocationHoursModels.Add(locationHoursModel);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(myModel);
        }
```

How can I go about creating a display template or a create view for the `Days` type of attribute for this MVC?

Comment: First remove the `[Bind(Include = ..)]`. Are you wanting to dynamically add a new `ExceptionDay` and/or `RegularDay` or just edit existing items? Why are you using `@Html.DisplayFor` when its an editor template and why are you passing the template name? (the `EditorTemplate` should be named `RegularDay.cshtml`

Comment: 1. Removed the bind attributes. 2. I want to create a new item but eventually i'd like to edit dynamically as well. 3. `@Html.DisplayFor` was a mistake. I fixed it. 3. The template is called explicitly because my DisplayFor/EditorFor is for RegularDays but my templates are for the `RegularDay` model/class. I could create a template for the `RegularDays` model but I don't know how to access the `RegularDay` model when the model at the top is `RegularDays`

Comment: To create a new item you will have to use javascript. If you need an example, let me know. Your templates should be `RegularDay.cshtml` with `@model RegularDay` (ditto for `ExceptionDay`) and be located in the `View/Shared/EditorTemplates` (or `Views/YourController/EditorTemplates`) folder and called as `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.RegularDays)` etc. By passing a template name you lose the autogenerated index naming of the controls